# User logged in, but no stats into application insights

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-insights

I've set up a facebook login button on my website. Basic idea is to collect the email addresses of the user. Simple task, I guess.

I have few users already connected but when I go to the app there is no new users...

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11799135/Capture22.PNG - here is the preview...

Should I wait for few hours/days?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The data that you access through Insights is at most 48 hours old.

All daily, weekly and monthly Insights data are aggregated according to PDT (Pacific Daylight Time).

Source: [insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/)